# Hyphenation issues with acronyms (acrlong) and with compound words

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms

I'm getting a few "overfull \hbox" error with compounded words of the "longword1-longword2" kind, with "longword1-" exceeding the margin. This can be solved by defining custom hyphenation ("\long-word1-longword2").

**Issue #1:** I have many different occurences with different words and I'd like to avoid to manually fix all of them.

**Issue #2:** I noticed that

```
\hyphenation{long-word1-longword2}
```

does not work, maybe because of the hyphen between the two words.

**Issue #3:** most of these words are defined using *glossary* package:

```
\RequirePackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
```

For example, one of the acronyms is defined as

```
\newacronym{cbm}{CBM}{Condition-based Maintenance}
```

and when I call it with

```
...a component (\textit{``\acrlong{cbm}''}) and detect...
```

the "on-" is exceeding the margin.

I tried the following solutions:

```
\newacronym{cbm}{CBM}{Condi\-ti\-on-based Maintenance}

\hyphenation{Condi-ti-on-based Condi-ti-on}
```

and none of them works, while replacing the \acrlong command with the full text *Condi-ti-on-based Maintenance* does work.

---

So my questions are:

1. is there any way to do an automatic hyphenation for these "longword1-" when I am NOT using \acrlong?
2. is there any way to use custom hyphenation within the \acrlong command?
3. how do I use \hyphenation{} with words containing a dash?

PS: If it could matter, I'm using book class.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a known 'feature' of TeX that the hyphenation algorithm does not hyphenate words already containing a hyphen. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/35864

Comment: I found a working solution for issue #3, which still requires to use "\-" in the acronym definition

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69275/acronym-does-not-hyphenate-in-text

Comment: depending on where and how the already hyphenated words are being input, they might be amenable to applying a (manual) workaround `xxx\hyph yyy`, defining `\hyph` as `\slash` is defined by latex; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121955/579 for uses of that command and a pointer to its definition.  (`\hyph` is defined for tugboat for exactly this reason.)