# Why does acronyms list of acro overflow hbox (horizontal page overflow)?

Tags: formatting, acronyms, acro

I have a file similar to this one (simplified version):

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered, leveldown}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69585/98645
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@acl}{\AC@foo}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@acl}{\AC@foo}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@foo}{\hskip\z@\AC@acl}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@foo}{\hskip\z@\AC@acl}{}{}
\makeatother

% acronyms
\usepackage{acro}

% deutsch
\usepackage[norsk, english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[norsk, english, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführunsgzeichen mit \enquote

\renewcommand{\small}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} % 1,5 zeilig
\usepackage[
    left=2.5cm, % 2,5 cm - 3,0 cm
    right=1.5cm, % 1,5 cm - 2,0 cm
    top=2.0cm, % 2,0 cm - 2,5 cm
    bottom=2.0cm, % 1,5 cm - 2,0 cm
    % includefoot,
    heightrounded
]{geometry}

\DeclareAcronym{sarsCov}{
    short = {SARS-CoV-2},
    long = {Schweres-akutes-Atemwegssyndrom-Coronavirus 2},
    foreign = \enquote{\foreignlanguage{english}{Severe acute respiratory syndrome-related coronavirus}},
    foreign-lang = english,
    % cite = {sarsCov2Preprint, sarsCov2Nature},
    first-style = reversed
}
% […]

begin{document}
    % […]
    Name: \ac{sarsCov}

    \printacronyms[
    name=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
    heading=section
    ]
\end{document}
```

Now I thought acro should make everything correctly, but for that long acronym entry I get:

> Overfull \hbox (39.72452pt too wide) in paragraph

…and it very clearly visually does not look correct:

[image: acronym for Sars-CoV-19 overflows page]

I thought with all wrapping and loading the English babel package etc. it should be able to wrap that word properly.

This is texlive-2019-19.fc32.src.rpm (svn52662).

**Edit:** I am not sure whether it is the same problem, so please forgive me if not, but actually also when I use a long acronym anywhere else in the content, it is not broken up:

```
% (same as before)

\DeclareAcronym{dsgvo}{
    short = DSGVO,
    long = {Datenschutz-Grundverordnung},
    foreign = {\enquote{\foreignlanguage{english}{General Data Protection Regulation}}, GDPR}, % GDPR
    foreign-lang = english,
    cite = dsgvo-eu-2016-679
}

% […]

begin{document}
    % […]
    Name der \ac{dsgvo}

    % […]

    \printacronyms[
    name=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
    heading=section
    ]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I have to add [that this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69585/98645) does not help either.

[image: DSGVO overflows \hbox too in document]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preface

I'm assuming you are version 2.xx of `acro`.

`foreign-lang = english` already sets the babel language, adding `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}` is superfluous.

#### First problem

Your problem is that in words with hyphens like `syndrome-related` (la)tex cannot hyphenate the word anymore anywhere else than where the hyphen is. This is why in German you usually use the babel shorthand `"=` if you want to allow hyhenation in the rest of the word: `Haftpflicht"=Versicherung`.  This won't help in your problem *ad hoc* because the German shorthands are not activated for English.

The fastest solution would be to explicitly add break points like `syn\-drome-related`. If you want to use the babel shorthand you need to add it to English:

```
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}\useshorthands{"}}
```

and activate it before defining the acronym because shorthands otherwise don't work in the preamble:

```
\shorthandon{"}
\DeclareAcronym{sarsCov}{
  ...
  foreign = \enquote{Severe acute respiratory syndrome"=related coronavirus},
  foreign-lang = english,
  ...
}
```

You'll get

[image]

#### Second problem

If you type the text of your second problem explicitly you get the same output. It's not `acro`'s fault:

```
\section{foo bar}

Nach der \ac{dsgvo}

\section{foo bar}

Nach der Datenschutz-Grundverordnung („General Data Protection Regulation“, GDPR, DSGVO)~[?]
```

[image]

These kinds of problems often vanish by adding `\usepackage{microtype}` to the preamble. This package is always a good idea, anyway…

If it doesn't help and you cannot rephrase the sentence you can always try to use `sloppypar`:

```
\begin{sloppypar}
  Nach der \ac{dsgvo}
\end{sloppypar}
```

[image]

#### Notes

- I added the `showframe` option to `geometry` for the example output to show the chosen page dimensions. Other than that I just copied your preamble.
- I'm not sure all the hyphens in “Schweres-akutes-Atemwegssyndrom-Coronavirus 2” are all correct, but…

Comment: Hm yeah, I thought babel would handle all that – after all that is *why* I actually use `\foreignlanguage`. Especially in English, where these even are single words.

Comment: @rugk as I said in my answer: if you use `foreign-lang` then `acro` already uses `\foreignlanguage` itself. This sets the correct hyphenation rules but doesn't change how tex treats composite words with explicit hyphens. That's why babel provides the shorthands. Not for English, though, as explicit hyphens are rare in English...

Comment: I forgot to add, I actually also use this, so AFAIK this should do it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69585/98645

Comment: @rugk I edited my answer to address your second problem, too

Comment: Thanks yeah, also needed to add `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{1em}` that helped, too.